# Error when using jinja2 as django template engine: cannot import name 'Environment'

Tags: django, jinja2

I followed the recommendations in the django docs for enabling jinja2 as my template engine:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2

But then I was getting an intermittent error from django:

> cannot import name 'Environment'

I'm running on Windows 10, django 1.9, python 3.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried many things.
Finally, I tried renaming the file from jinja2.py to jinja2_bridge.py

That seems to fix it.

Conjecture: the module  jinja2 is on the python path, but if the filename is also jinja2 then python might be trying to re-import the same file... well, just a guess.

Here's confirmation of the workaround -- seems to be misinformation in the django docs
https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/django-users/pytjLOVUwmM/eG7FOjnq7gUJ

Also, see django bug 24646:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24646